# Is there a way to draw merged cells on Google Chart Table?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have designed a general purpose Dashboard editor based on Google Charts API.

I have been finding a way to draw merged cells on tables. I have readed all documentation about that, but there is not way trough API.

Do you know some way or workaround to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm lazy, so I'm going to take the liberty of assuming that you have access to JQuery. You can do this in pure Javascript dom manipulation but seriously? Life's too short...

There is a workaround, but it has some caveats

The table visualisation is clever but, at the end of the day, it still just a table and can be managed as one.

Something like this...

```
$("td:contains('Blah blag blaf')").attr("colspan","2").next("td").remove()
```

So that's looking for a cell that contains 'Blah blag blaf', merging it across two columns and removes the next (now redundant) cell

Alternatively

```
$("#chart_div tr:eq(3) td:eq(2)").attr("colspan","2").next("td").remove()
```

Assuming your table is in #chart_div, this does the same thing but based on row and column.

There is a catch though... The table is re-drawn from data on sort - so, if your table is sortable you'll have to capture the event and reapply your merge